# How to avoid error using the chr function while decoding ASCII?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ascii, decode, chr

I've worked on a code to "encode" song lyrics pasted into a text file, using the ord function. This is the code below:

```
import os

filename = os.path.abspath("WeWillRockYou.txt")
out_file = open('WeWillRockYou2.txt', 'w')
readFile = open (filename, 'r')
for line in readFile:
    for char in line:
        if not char == "\n":
            out_file.write(str(ord(char)))
        else:
            out_file.write(char)

out_file.close()
```

After, these song lyrics are put into a new text file, but as ASCII. Now I'm attemping to make a code which will "decode" the song lyrics and write them into a new text file as they were originally, however I get an error. The decode code in the one below:

```
import os

filename = os.path.abspath("WeWillRockYou2.txt")
out_file = open('WeWillRockYou3.txt', 'w')
readFile = open (filename, 'r')
for line in readFile:
    for num in line:
        if not num == "\n":
            out_file.write(int(chr(num)))
        else:
            out_file.write(char)

out_file.close()
```

But I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 16, in <module>
    out_file.write(int(chr(num)))
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Any help on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated! Thankss!

Comment: `num` is being read from a file, so it will be a *string*. You need to use `out_file.write(chr(int(num)))`

Comment: you are going to have tonnes of problems with this ie is "1132" = "11" &"32" ? or "113" and "2"? or "1" and "132" ? especially since the original format will be bytes from 0-255

Comment: you at a minimum need to use a delimiter... and really i dont understand why you would want to do this? it doesnt make sense... it requires many more bytes to store in this way ...

Comment: I'm doing this for an assignment! Is there no way to avoid these problems?